# iOS rightBarButtonItem on UINavigationController in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

I'm trying to put a `rightBarButtonItem` on a second view controller of an `UINavigationViewController` stack.

I'm creating and setting the button in `viewDidLoad` of the view controller that I want to show. My actual code looks like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    menu_button_ = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "menu"),
        style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain ,
        target: self, action: "OnMenuClicked:")

    self.navigationController!.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = menu_button_
}
```

What am I missing? The button doesn't appear.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You should set the `menu_button_` as the `rightBarButtonItem` of your `viewController` rather than the `navigationController`.

Try

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = menu_button_
```

instead of

```
self.navigationController!.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = menu_button_
```

Comment: Any idea why it's not working when going through the navigation controller?

Comment: Does "instead" mean "instead of"? I'm confused

Comment: @DaniSpringer Yes, thanks. I edited. I mean use the top one, DO NOT use the bottom one.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

try with following `code.` it works for me.

```
let homeButton : UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "LeftButtonTitle", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "")

let logButton : UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "RigthButtonTitle", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "")

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = homeButton
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = logButton
```

And if you want to settle out `custom image` then please check with apple guidelines on below link.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/BarIcons.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH21-SW1

Answer (score 3):

In Swift 5

```
//For righter button item
let rightBtn = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "rightmenu"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(onClickMethod))//Change your function name and image name here
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBtn
//self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [rightBtn, anotherBtn] //If you want to add more buttons add like this

//This is your function
@objc func onClickMethod() {
    print("Left bar button item")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create an extension of UINavigationItem like -

```
extension UINavigationItem {
    func addSettingButtonOnRight(){
        let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
    button.setTitle("setting", for: .normal)
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15.0)
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    button.backgroundColor = .gray
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 25)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(gotSettingPage), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)

        self.rightBarButtonItem = barButton
    }

    @objc func gotSettingPage(){

    }
}
```

And call it from viewDidLoad() like -

```
self.navigationItem.addSettingButtonOnRight()
```

Comment: you create an extension juste for this? I wouldn't do this, I would rather create an utils instance class and put this function inside, we generally create an extension for a function that we will call many times, I don't this you will call your function many times